# Product of a factor module by an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let M be a finitely generated A-module, N a sub-module of M, I is contained in Jacobson of ring A.
How to prove the following equation?
I(M/N)=(IM+N)/N.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is true for any ideal of $A$, not only for ideals contained in the Jacobson radical of $A$.